# Check a string is double without failing with a NumberFormatException

Tags: java, regex, double

I would like to avoid a try-catch to check if a string is in fact a valid double value.

In Double class java-doc it show a regex to do just that. I find it a bit frustrating that they [Java Language/Std Lib. Spec folk] didn't simply decided to add a convenient method to do such a check or constant with that regex or pattern.

Does anyone know of a popular package (e.g. like jakarta commons-math that implements such a test. I prefer to avoid copy-paste that javadoc regex to my code since it seems to be something so standard that would expect to have some implementations out there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NumberUtils` from Apache Commons provides with a static method `NumberUtils.isCreatable(someString)` which checks whether a   valid Java number or not. you can read full docs from [this link](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/math/NumberUtils.html#isCreatable-java.lang.String-)

sample code:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    String doubleString = "5.05";
    if(NumberUtils.isCreatable(doubleString){
         System.out.println("Yayy! a double");
    }else{
         System.out.println("Oops!!!");
    }
}
```

[Dependency](https://search.maven.org/classic/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.apache.commons%22%20AND%20a%3A%22commons-lang3%22) required:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
    <version>3.7</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks, seems to be what I'm looking for. The code does not use the pattern included in Double JavaDoc. However it look complex enough that is likely to do the exhaustive check. Will take your answer unless someone else comes up with a competing solution soon

Comment: Try ```NumberUtils.isParsable(String)```, Unlike ```NumberUtils.isCreatable()```, this method won’t accept hexadecimal numbers, scientific notations or strings ending with any type qualifier, i.e. ‘f’, ‘F’, ‘d’ ,’D’ ,’l’or‘L’. Also ```NumberUtils.isCreatable()``` will return false in this ```NumberUtils.isCreatable("09")``` since it will treat "09" as an octal value and "09” is not a valid octal number. In bench marking ```NumberUtils_isParsable``` is more optimal compared to ```NumberUtils.isCreatable()```